# Filtering a datatime set from the starting and ending year with Pandas Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

How would I be able to write a code that will enable the starting and the ending year in `dates`. I want to use either pandas or numpy to show the starting and the ending year.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

dates = ['2017-09-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-02-01 00:00:00', '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '2018-04-01 00:00:00', '2018-05-01 00:00:00', '2018-06-01 00:00:00', '2018-07-01 00:00:00', '2018-08-01 00:00:00', '2018-09-01 00:00:00', '2018-10-01 00:00:00', '2018-11-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

Expected Output:

```
Starting year: 2017
Ending year: 2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case let us do

```
pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dates)).dt.year.agg(StartYear = 'min', EndYear = 'max')
Out[245]: 
StartYear    2017
EndYear      2019
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
mn, mx = (m := pd.to_datetime(dates)).min(), m.max()
print(f"Starting year: {mn.year}\nEnding year: {mx.year}")
```

Prints:

```
Starting year: 2017
Ending year: 2019
```